# How should I retrieve nextRecord resource?

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Response of REST API Endpoints has nextRecord URLs, but RESTClient seems to be not providing function to fetch resource by URLs.

How should I retrieve nextRecord?
Just using URLSession provided by Foundation?

Comment: It's `nextRecordsUrl`, and you use the SessionId that you should already have from the previous call.

Comment: Thank you for the response @sfdcfox .
What I wanted to know was if I should use URLSession of Foundation or something else that is provided by Salesforce SDK.
Anyway I finally know that using URLSession to fetching nextRecord is recommended way.

I appreciate your answer.

(SessionURL was a type for "URLSession". I'm sorry for the mistake.)